# How to reorder Django-Graphene sub-query?

Tags: django, graphql, django-oscar, graphene-python

I am trying to reorder my ProductLandingPageImageNode according to a 'order' field on my ProductLandingpageImage Model.

If this would be a direct query I could write a resolve method, but I cannot find out how this is possible on a sub-query.

MAIN QUERY:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = [relay.Node, ]

  product_oscar = graphene.List(ProductNode)
  productByID = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ProductNode)


  def resolve_product_oscar(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Product.objects.all()
```

PRODUCTNODE:

```
class ProductNode(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    interfaces = (relay.Node, )
    filter_fields = {
      "slug" : ['iexact']
    }
```

PRODUCTLANDINGPAGEIMAGENODE:

```
class ProductLandingpageImageNode(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = ProductLandingpageImage
    interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

How to solve this?

---

LANDINGPAGEIMAGE MODEL on request:

```
class AbstractProductLandingpageImage(models.Model):
  """
    A landingpageimage of a product
  """
  product = models.ForeignKey(
    'catalogue.Product',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='landingpage_image',
    verbose_name=_("Product landingpage"))
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(_("Date created"), auto_now_add=True)
  original = models.ImageField(
    _("Landingpage original"), upload_to=settings.OSCAR_IMAGE_FOLDER, max_length=255, blank=True)

  ORDER_CHOICES = (
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 5),
    (6, 6),
  )

  order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, choices=ORDER_CHOICES, blank=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
    app_label = 'catalogue'
    # Any custom models should ensure that this ordering is unchanged, or
    # your query count will explode. See AbstractProduct.primary_image.
    ordering = ["order"]
    verbose_name = _('Product landingpage image')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Product landingpage images')
```

The default ordering in the Meta does somehow not work. What is also strange when I Graphql query for the order value is not not return "1, 2, 3..." but "A_1, A_2..."

Comment: You don't show your models, but I'm guessing that you want to create an explicit resolver for your ProductLandingpageImage model in your ProductNode that has the ordering that you want, instead of using the default resolve method that is created by DjangoObjectType.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I need.

Comment: @MarkChackerian can you please show me how to write an explicit resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this.  Since you don't list your Product model, I just made up the name of the field on Product that references the image, so you should rename that.  If there's a many-to-one relationship  relationship between product and image maybe you want a different field name.

```
import graphene
from graphene.django.types import DjangoObjectType

class ProductNode(DjangoObjectType):
    name_of_your_image_field = graphene.Field(ProductLandingpageImageNode)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        ... other Meta data


    def resolve_name_of_your_image_field(self, info):  # rename to match field
        # Put the code that returns a single ProductLandingpageImage instance here
        # graphene-django will convert your ProductLandingPageImage instance into a ProductLandingpageImageNode
```

This is for returning a single `ProductLandingPageIMage` . If you want to return multiple instances, then change the field definition to a list

```
    name_of_your_image_field = graphene.List(ProductLandingpageImageNode)
```

and then in your resolver return multiple ProductLandingPageImage instances -- for example a queryset that is sorted the way that you want it.